# How to made QGraphicsView fullscreen?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a QDialog window of size 800x480 and my sample image also have same size (800x480), But when it put it in QGraphicsView it showing a small space between image and window, how to avoid this space (yellow color )
[image]

I am using Qt5 in windows10

My code is

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene= new QGraphicsScene(this);
    QPixmap pix(qApp->applicationDirPath()+QDir::separator()+"testImage.png");
    pixItem = scene->addPixmap(pix);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    ui->graphicsView->showMaximized();
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::showEvent(QShowEvent *)
{
    ui->graphicsView->fitInView(scene->sceneRect(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);

}
```

And my xml generated by qt designer is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>480</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <property name="sizeConstraint">
    <enum>QLayout::SetMaximumSize</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="leftMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="topMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="rightMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="bottomMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="spacing">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView">
     <property name="sizePolicy">
      <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="MinimumExpanding">
       <horstretch>0</horstretch>
       <verstretch>0</verstretch>
      </sizepolicy>
     </property>
     <property name="autoFillBackground">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShadow">
      <enum>QFrame::Sunken</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
      <enum>QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustIgnored</enum>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I tried by adding image size bigger than 800x480 but the space is there

Comment: Use `QWindow` instead of `QDialog`, and then https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#showFullScreen

Comment: Firstly i tried in QMainWindow then i moved to QDialog , both showing same

Comment: When i added  QRectF rectF(10,10,780,460);
    scene= new QGraphicsScene(rectF,this); i got the picture with out yellow background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used both QDialog and QMainwindow, but both of them have same problem with QGrapgicsView.
Finally I changed QGraphicsView with QLabel and it does not have this problem.